# J/Python gethostbyaddr() returns: ip or domain?

Tags: python, windows-7, jython

I have a Jython application that takes the client's IP address and then runs it through gethostbyaddr(). Sometimes it returns a triple of ip addresses, sometimes we get a domain name (xxxx.domain.com). We would like to use the full computer names since the IP addresses are dynamic. We've decided that there is some network or workstation setting that is preventing the return of the domain name. This is a Windows network (Quick edit: The IP addresses are internal to our network, not outside).

So the question: Is there a better way to get the full computer name, or does anyone happen to know a setting that we can change?

Code snip:

```
print socket.gethostbyaddr('{ip}')
```

Thanks!

Edit:

```
 print socket.getfqdn( socket.gethostbyaddr('{ip}')[0] )
```

sometimes returns an IP address, sometimes it returns the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working like this, I'd say it's a bug:

```
stromberg@aw50 ~/src/stackoverflow/pyc-from-java $ /usr/local/jython-2.5.3b1/bin/jython  
Jython 2.5.3b1 (2.5:5fa0a5810b25, Feb 22 2012, 12:39:02)  
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_31  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import socket  
>>> import platform  
>>> platform.node()  
'aw50'  
>>> socket.gethostbyname('aw50')  
'10.0.30.50'  
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('10.0.30.50')  
('aw50.av1.ca.us.gaikai.int', ['aw50.av1.ca.us.gaikai.int'], ['10.0.30.50'])  
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('10.0.30.50')[0]  
'aw50.av1.ca.us.gaikai.int'  
>>>
```

You could try the latest 2.5 beta or 2.7 alpha.

Comment: This does work for the server; however we are using Tomcat+Jython to serve a web application. We need the _client's_ IP address/full computer name.

Comment: Perhaps you've already done this, but if not try socket.getpeername  http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername...

Comment: Unfortunately our Jython build does not appear to have this module installed.